# Is the utmt parameter needed when sending a custom variable gif request in google analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I am trying to use google analytics on the server side using custom variables.

Google says the following about the utmt parameter:

> Indicates the type of request, which is one of: event, transaction, item, or custom variable. If this value is not present in the GIF request, the request is typed as page.

However when I use http headers, I do not see the utmt parameter being sent even when I am defining custom variables. 
Is it necessary? If so, could you provide a query string example?

EDIT: This is the javascript code that I'm using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-123456789-1']);
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 1, 'Test', 'Test', 2]);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

(function() {
var ga = document.createElement('script'); 
ga.type = 'text/javascript'; 
ga.async = true;
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; 
s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();

</script>
```

Comment: "I do not see the utmt parameter being sent" So you have a pb with your code. Please provide some code sample.

Comment: @greg Sorry about that. I have included the code and the gif request now.

Comment: Your code is a standard javascript tracking code, not "server side" as you ask...

Comment: @greg Yes, I am asking this question in order to know whether I need the utmt parameter when I implement it on server side since I am not seeing it in the standard way.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the [Google Analytics for Mobile Websites](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/other/mobileWebsites) code? It's useful as a reference for generating the tracking GIF request. Also, be aware that there's a limit of approximately 500 tracking requests per user session.

Comment: @mike Yes, I have thanks. However it doesn't support custom variables. But you're right, it's very useful for reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Contrary to what the documentation suggests, you can't set a customvar outside a pageview or event tracking. And `_setCustomVar` don't call the GA servers by itself.
`utmt` parameter value can only be 'event', 'item', 'transaction', and has a pageview value if not set.

Custom variables are passed with calls from pageview or event (as briefly [explained here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCustomVariables#recommended))

In your exemple, the custom variable is send with a `_trackPageview` call (you can see it at `utme=8(Test)9(Test)11(2)`).
Pageview is the default value for `utmt`, so there is no need to specify it here.

Note : the "custom variable" in the documentation refer to the [old `_setVar` function](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiBasicConfiguration#_gat.GA_Tracker_._setVar) which is deprecated.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I don't know why google documentation would be wrong. :/